# Angular Date pipe adds plus dot after year component

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, angular-pipe

I'm using Angular version 2.4.5.

If I use the date pipe without any format it creates double dots after the year. If I use the pipe with the format: 'yyyyMM.dd.' it gives the correct date format

- `{{startDate | date}}` => 2017..07.07.
- `{{startDate | date: 'yyyyMM.dd.'}}` => 2017.07.07.

Which means that I can not set this as the value of a date input because it waits for the format `yyyy-MM-dd` and yyyy always have a plus dot that causes an error on input element. Neither of these work:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate" [ngModel]="currentItem.startDate | date: 'y-MM-dd'"
(ngModelChange)="currentItem.startDate = $event" name="startdate">
```

How can I solve this without using a new model with a correctly converted date string?

**Update 2017-07-12**:
currentItem.startDate is a Date() object eg:

```
let currentItem.startDate = new Date();
```

The locale I'm trying to use is 'hu-HU' but the two dots were present without any locale provider. In that case the date pipe without any format strings gave the correct format for the input. (yyyy-MM-dd)

```
{{currentItem.startDate | date}}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Which nationality is the application running on? What's in `currentItem.startDate`? DatePipe is only reliable in Chrome and Opera due to the Internationalization API. I'd suggest using a different pipe from a library like [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) or making your own custom pipe.

Comment: @snaplemouton I've updated the question with the answers. The browser is Chrome and I started to use a different variable only for the correct date format for the input. It's working but I'll check the moment pipe you suggested.